# Specify Proxy Server on specific Search Service Application

Tags: sharepoint-server, search

I currently have 2 SSA on my farm, A and B, the problem is when I set the proxy server on SSA "A", It's set on the SSA "B" too. Is it a normal behavior or a misconfiguration ?

I set the proxy settings on Central Admin then in Search Administration, not in Farm Search Administration.

Do you how can I solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance,

Maxime

Answer (score 0):

Go to CA > Manage web applications > Select the web application > Click "Service Connections" in the ribbon. Make sure if you have selected SSA "A" for your web application.

If you selected the right SSA for your web application, pay attention that for setting the proxy, you need to go to "Farm Search Administration" to configure your changes(not in Search Administration ). Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/configure-proxy-server-settings-for-search

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply,

The service connections are correct and the proxy settings has been set at farm search administration level.

Unfortunately It doesn't crawl the external sites and internal site. (with proxy : external sites are crawling but not internal,  without proxy : internal sites are crawling but not external)

Even within the checkbox "Bypass proxy server for local (intranet) addresses) selected.

[image]

So my idea was to create a second SSA, and set the proxy settings on search administration level. One within, one without.

﻿[image]

I would like to set a proxy settings for one, not for both :

[image]

But what is happen when I do : it's changing on both SSA, that's my problem.

Any idea why ?

Thank you

Maxime,